# Android Emulator fails to start any AVD (Win Vista)

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, windows-vista

Android emululator fails to start with the following message:

> Failed to create Context 0x3005
>   emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
>   Warning: No DNS servers found

I have installed the latest Android SDK, installed all tools and extras and several Android versions in the SDK Manager, and created several AVDs with various settings in the AVD Manager, but no matter which AVD I try to start, it fails with the above message.

I have also installed Eclipse ADT, and running projects on an actual Android device connected with USB works fine.

**OS:** Windows Vista Ultimate, Service Pack 2 (32 bit)

I *have* googled it, and found a lot of similar questions, but none which helped me solve the problem. I have read through the documentation at developer.android.com as well, but I could not find any solution there either.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it on my own.

All I had to do was right-click **AVD Manager.exe** and choose *Run as administrator*.

Comment: I am using android studio at window vista and getting the same error

Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer
I tried to click avd manager shows error

failed to execute tools/android.bat
file not found please suggest me solutions